# AEM page properties dialog not showing the tabs for author users

Tags: aem, jcr

In the AEM page trying to add a new tab for the page properties dialog. The new added elements are showing and those are working fine when I logged in as a administrator, but when I logged in a authoring user, in the page properties the newly added tab is showing as empty. Tried all other alternatives and checked the permissions too. Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Aby errors in the JS/network console?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide as much detail as possible — When you start a vanilla install of AEM and install your code, does it work there? How about if you add your tabs to the default Geometrixx page dialog? When you say you checked the permissions, where does your dialog live in the folder structure? Can a non-admin user get to other dialogs OK? Can they get to the XML of the dialog in the browser?

Comment: no errors @toniedzwiedz

Answer (score 1):

Give Read permission to content-authors group for etc/cloudservices, it will resolve this issue.